# Laravel join two database tables using models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How do I join these two tables from two models:

Student.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'students';

}
```

And StudentDetails.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProductDetails extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'student_details';
}
```

Then use these two models in a single controller:

```
    use App\Student;
    use App\StudentDetails;    
            public function index()
            {
                return Product::latest()
                  ->join('StudentDetails','StudentDetails.product_id','Product.product_id')
                  ->get();

                //I dont know what the right approach is but i was thinking of 
                  doing something like this
            }
```

I am confused as to what the use of the StudentDetails model is for.

I just got it to work by doing something like this:

```
return Student::latest()
                  ->join('student_details','student_details.student_id','student.student_id')
                  ->get();
```

Comment: show your database structure for these two tables

Comment: @InzamamIdrees I've edited my post and i seem to got it to work. And now im confused do i really need the 2nd Model or just the first one? Now thats my question

Comment: Why do you need this join? Do you want to fetch the products that have student details? Or do you want the products with their student details?

Comment: You may use relationships and that's when both the models come to play. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations

Comment: @Jerodev my bad that was the wrong paste. Edited just in case.

Comment: @EmberSpirit you still have not to show database tables...... and what is the question what you want to fetch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't even want to create `StudentDetails`to get data using the code you have used.

the model `StudentDetails`is need only when you get the data using relationships.
for that you have to mention the relation ship between both tables. assuming it has-many relationship.

```
class Product extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'students';
   public function studentDetails(){
    return $this->hasMany(StudentDetails::class);
  }
}
```

Now the relationship mentioned. 
Now you can fetch the data using the below query.

```
$product = Product::has('studentDetails')->get();
```

Note: this will return the collection, if you want to get the studentDetails's id,
you have to do like this

```
$product->studentDetails[0]->id
```

or

```
$product->studentDetails->first()->id
```

Hope this clear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your case, but such simple joins can be easily and cleanly achieved by relations *([checkout the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships))*

As far as I understand you are trying to get, the products *-students-* along with their product details *-student_details-*.. if this is right, then you can just have

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'students';

    public function details()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductDetails::class); // or just use your kind of relation
    }
}
```

and then

```php
public function index()
{
    return Product::with('details')
      ->latest()
      ->get(); // this is exactly equal to your join
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to make relation on model then you can do like:

```
   return Student::join('student_details','student_details.student_id','student.student_id')
-> select(stydent.*,student_details.*)->get();
```